# reading concurrently but locking with edits

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

I'm looking for a solution that allows multiple threads to read the shared resource (concurrency permitted) but then locks these reading threads once a thread enters a mutating block, to achieve best of both world.

```
class Foo {

    Map<String, String> sharedResource;

    public void read() // multiple reading threads allowed, concurrency ok, lock this only if a thread enters the mutating block below.
    {
         // read concurrently unless a thread enters mutating blocks add/remove
    }

    public void add() // this should lock any threads entering this block as well as lock the reading threads above
    {
        synchronized(sharedResource) // lock remove and read
        {
        }
    }

    public void remove() // lock add and read
    {
        synchronized(sharedResource)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Is there such a solution in Java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a classic read/write lock scenario:

```
class Foo {

    Map<String, String> sharedResource;
    ReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

    public void read() {
         lock.readLock().lock();
         try {
             // read
         } finally {
             lock.readLock().unlock();
         }
    }

    public void add() {
         lock.writeLock().lock();
         try {
             // add
         } finally {
             lock.writeLock().unlock();
         }
    }

    public void remove() {
         lock.writeLock().lock();
         try {
             // remove
         } finally {
             lock.writeLock().unlock();
         }
    }
}
```

The read lock can be shared, but the write lock is exclusive to both reads and writes.

Comment: Thanks for the example, this seems to be the one, quick question I've worked with `ConcurrentDictionary` in `C#`, what do you say about `ConcurrentHashMap` in java, is it something comparable to what you have given me as an answer?

Comment: Assuming it's actually a Map we're talking about then doing a read in some Map implementations does actually mutate the map: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html. You need to be sure the Map implementation is coherent with your locking strategy. In addition, there are also Map implementations that effectively allow multiple readers without external locking: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html.

Comment: @user2727195 `ConcurrentHashMap` is usually the recommended solution in cases like yours.

Comment: ok. it may be inefficient but just for the info, If I mark all the methods (`read`, `add`, `remove`) as `synchronized`, is it essentially same as using your answer as well as using `ConcurrentHashMap` (of course no synchronized methods)?

Comment: @JohnH That's interesting. I've always heard of the potential for livelock in some map implementations, but I hadn't considered that some maps explicitly write on `get()`. Though your comment is arguably more relevant to the question than to my answer.

Comment: @user2727195 If all access is fully `synchronized` your code will be thread safe. Performance is another question.

Comment: ok, one more confusion I need to get out of the way. Let's imagine same class `Foo` with `synchronized add()`, `synchronized remove()` and `read` without synchronization. `Thread A` calls `foo.add()`, will `Thread B` will be blocked calling `read`? My understanding is none of the threads will be able to call any method of the `foo` once a `synchronized` method is in progress.

Comment: @user2727195 That's incorrect. Synchronization has to be mutual between both threads.

Comment: didn't get fully, please tell me more, I've read the java doc on Concurrency but still not clear, question, if a synchronized method is in progress, can other non-synchronized methods be invoked by other threads on the same object?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136002/discussion-between-shmosel-and-user2727195).